# How to detect a React component vs. a React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`React.isValidElement` tests true for both React components as well as React elements. How would I test, specifically, that an object is a React component? Currently, I'm doing it by testing `typeof obj.type === 'function'`, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: obj.type can be a symbol or a string as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ReactComponent.prototype.isReactComponent = {};
```

## 33 of /node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponent.js

Install using npm. At this point, there is no direct method available to check for its validity. What you are doing is correct.

Comment: The above solutions doesn't insist on installing the node module. It was referring to a line in code for more reference.

Comment: Dan Abramov: ".isReactComponent is an impl detail and we reserve the right to change it in the future" (https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/787739945301635073)

Comment: I used `instanceof()`, it worked perfectly, and it's only 10 characters, whereas ReactComponent.js is an entire package.  Why not just use something built-in that's much shorter?

Answer (score 104):

If you really want to type check for

- component vs element
- class vs functional component
- DOM vs Composite Element

You could try something like this.

```
function isClassComponent(component) {
    return (
        typeof component === 'function' && 
        !!component.prototype.isReactComponent
    )
}

function isFunctionComponent(component) {
    return (
        typeof component === 'function' && 
        String(component).includes('return React.createElement')
    )
}

function isReactComponent(component) {
    return (
        isClassComponent(component) || 
        isFunctionComponent(component)
    )
}

function isElement(element) {
    return React.isValidElement(element);
}

function isDOMTypeElement(element) {
    return isElement(element) && typeof element.type === 'string';
}

function isCompositeTypeElement(element) {
    return isElement(element) && typeof element.type === 'function';
}
```

**USE**

```
// CLASS BASED COMPONENT
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render(){
      return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}

const foo = <Foo />;

//FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT
function Bar (props) { return <h1>World</h1> }
const bar = <Bar />;

// REACT ELEMENT
const header = <h1>Title</h1>;

// CHECK
isReactComponent(Foo); // true
isClassComponent(Foo); // true
isFunctionComponent(Foo); // false
isElement(Foo); // false

isReactComponent(<Foo />) // false
isElement(<Foo />) // true
isDOMTypeElement(<Foo />) // false
isCompositeTypeElement(<Foo />) // true

isReactComponent(Bar); // true
isClassComponent(Bar); // false
isFunctionComponent(Bar); // true
isElement(Bar); // false

isReactComponent(<Bar />) // false
isElement(<Bar />) // true
isDOMTypeElement(<Bar />) // false
isCompositeTypeElement(<Bar />) // true

isReactComponent(header); // false
isElement(header); // true
isDOMTypeElement(header) // true
isCompositeTypeElement(header) // false
```

[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/emanualjade/pen/MJjgNa?editors=0010)

Comment: The post seem to be missing any explanation why you posted the code nor how the code is expected to be used. This makes it low quality answer from SO standards.

Comment: I guess the case of isFunctionComponent is not valid anymore. By inspecting I found something like this `function FnChild(props) {
  return _react2.default.createElement('div', { id: 'child-fn' });
}`

Comment: Downvote because you don't mention that `String(component).includes('return React.createElement')` will not work in many cases.

Comment: Nice solution. It's interesting. Thanks

Comment: These are good ideas, but… a) `typeof component === 'function'` doesn't ensure the object has a prototype (arrow functions don't), so `component.prototype.isReactComponent` could produce a `TypeError`. b) `String(component).includes('return React.createElement')` may vary based on version and/or transpiler. c) `isReactComponent` is misleading considering that `isClassComponent` is a wrapper for the native `prototype.isReactComponent`. d) You can simplify the ternary expressions by just returning the result from the binary logical operators. You can clean this up & have a useful little library.

Comment: isFunctionComponent is unreliable for general use-case & while writing unit tests. Also, if I mimic the React function component structure and its instance, this will fail to detect the real component.

Comment: **[Demo with isClassComponent()](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shockley-k7krn?file=/src/index.j)** `var testcomp = <TestComponent />;   console.log(isClassComponent(testcomp);`.  Results: ***FALSE***.  I think you should test this before using it.

Comment: That solution doesn't take into account exotic components which are objects, such as those produced with `React.forwardsRef`.

Comment: I think the new best answer should be the facebook-supported package https://stackoverflow.com/a/62663794/7491536

Answer (score 46):

The simplest solution is:

```
React.isValidElement(element)
```

Comment: Might need to also do a `typeof element === 'function'` first, too. I was trying to render either a string or a React component

Comment: I get `false` on a working, functional React component, using this method :/

Comment: Long time has passed after this post publication. I suppose this method is not ultimate solution now. Try to use another recommendation if this is not working now.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to @EmanualJade answer, you can use this to check if a variable is a `function component`

```
React.isValidElement(Component())
```

As @Leonardo has pointed out, some compilers can cause this to fail:

```
String(component).includes('return React.createElement')
```

Comment: This feels more appropriate as a comment than an answer.

Comment: this is a good solution. Check if it's a function before

`typeof component === 'function' && !!React.isValidElement(component())`

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, with an old answer.

If you run into this issue, probably you'll want to check the `react-is` NPM package page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is

It's an official React module that takes into account details like ref forwarding, and memo to check for an element type.

To check if a value is an element type do: `ReactIs.isValidElementType(obj)`

Answer (score 1):

#### Checks if something is a *React* component or an Array of components:

```js
// checks if the argument is a React component or an Array of components
const isReactComp = v => React.isValidElement(v) ||
    (
      Array.isArray(v) && 
      v.every(node => React.isValidElement(node))
    );

const Test = ({children}) => <div>{isReactComp(children) + ''}</div>;
const MemoedComp = React.memo(({children}) => children);

// Render 
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Test>hello</Test>
    <Test><i>hello</i></Test>
    <Test>{[<i key={1}>hello</i>]}</Test>
    <Test><MemoedComp>hello</MemoedComp></Test>
  </div>
, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
class Test extends React.Component {}

console.log(!!Test.prototype.isReactComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to know what *class* you have for a particular *instance* of *an object variable*, then what you want is the ***instanceof*** operator...

```
function isHTMLElement(obj) {
    return (obj instanceof HTMLElement);
}
```

I tested with both `document.createElement('div')` (returns true) and `<someReactJSComponent />` (returns false).

`instanceof` is a powerful and useful tool in JavaScript.  Check out the official MDN documentation for it: [Mozilla Documentation Network: instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

> "The instanceof operator tests the presence of constructor.prototype in object's prototype chain."

*In addition*,  I have uploaded a code sample with a code-sandbox online to demonstrate the above principle...

***Online Code Sandbox :***

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmxjq27ol5

***Code :***

```
function App() { return (//insert JSX here//);};
const app = App();
const ele = document.createElement("div");
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(app, rootElement);
console.log(
  "Hello!  Is a React Component HTML???" +
    (app instanceof HTMLElement) +
    "|  Is an HTML element HTML???" +
    (ele instanceof HTMLElement) +
    "|"
);
```

***Code Results :***

```
Hello!  Is a React Element HTML???false|  Is an HTML element HTML???true|
```

No problem (tested Chrome and FF).  Just use `instanceof`.

Comment: A React Component is not html, that's all you've proved, how does that answer the question.

Comment: Hi, Learn for Fun!  Thanks for commenting!  `instanceOf` is well-documented in MDN developer documentation.  If there's any use in this answer, it's that all the other answers on this page will fail when used in the simple, 2-line sandbox demo I posted.  Cheers!

Comment: So you're saying, none of the answers will work when it comes to HTMLElements?

Comment: Hi, Learn for Fun!  I'm not sure what you're asking?  You can't just want me to confirm what I just said.  So, here's a demo with the top-scoring answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shockley-k7krn?file=/src/index.js CODE: `var testcomp = <TestComponent />;   console.log("TEST " + isClassComponent(testcomp) + "|");   // Results: "TEST false"`.  Notice the other functions, to determine if a react-element, use the `isClassComponent()`, yet it returns false for a legitimate React class component.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I think what Angshu31 was trying to say is that this answer is not helpful, because you cannot use this to determine if something is a React component. Your answer seems to assume that it's important to ascertain whether or not something is an HTML element, but this information is only useful when dealing with refs in particularly weird (bad?) ways. It unfortunately does not answer the question being asked.