# How to check if Dom Element or React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

When creating an HOC I'm not sure which kind of component will be wrapped, sometimes it is another React Component, sometimes it could be a plain DOM Element as `li` and `a`.

```
WrappedComp = myHOC(BaseComponent)
```

MyHOC will pass extra props to the wrapped component and in most of the cases this will work as it should.

But sometimes when BaseComponent is for example an `li` it will not accept the extra props and React will throw a warning `Unkown Prop Warning` saying that DOM element do not accept non-standard dom attributes: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

So how could I check if BaseComponent is a DOM element or else?
In case it is I will not pass the extra props to it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the output of `console.log(BaseComponent)` ?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the HOC over every component? Is it possible to wrap and export the components which you want to extend with it?

Comment: Easiest check is to see if its a `function`, typeof(BaseComponent) == "function", as for HTML components, react uses a `string`.

Comment: I'm not applying it on every component. I'm writing an npm package plugin that will be used alongside with react and other libraries so I will not be sure what the user will pass to it. Both DOM element and React Componet should be accepted

Comment: This check alone won't solve the issue though as React will give you these warnings over any component which has `propTypes` defined.

Comment: I've never done it, but I wonder if you can access the `propTypes` property of the component and only pass in your extra props if `propTypes` doesn't exist of contains your values?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199959/how-to-detect-a-react-component-vs-a-react-element/34406703

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:**
Check if element is of type `string` to check if element is a DOM element.
Check if element is of type `function` to check if element is a React component.

**Example:**

```js
  if (typeof BaseComponent.type === 'string') {
    return BaseComponent
  }
  // add props
```

**Long answer:**
As defined in [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), built-in components like `<li>` or `<span>` results in a string `'li'` or `'span'` being passed to `React.createElement`, e.g. `React.createElement("li")`.
Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

Consequently, a React Component is of type `function`, while a DOM Component is of type `string`.

The following `WrapperComponent` logs the `typeof child.type` of each child element. The output is `function`, `string`, `string`.

```js
function WrappedComponent({children}) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    console.log(typeof child.type)
    ...
  })
}

const BaseComponent = ({children}) => children

function App() {
  return (
    <WrappedComponent>
      <BaseComponent>This element has type of function</BaseComponent>
      <span>This element has type of string</span>
      <li>This element has type of string</li>
    </WrappedComponent>
  )
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Check if `BaseComponent` is a React Component, and add the required props.

```
if(BaseComponent.prototype.isReactComponent){
    //add props
}
```

Comment: Any doc about this?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b1b4a2fb252f26fe10d29ba60d85ff89a85ff3ec/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactBaseClasses.js#L33 you can see it in the source code.

Comment: I guess internal functions not documented shouldn't be used because they could change anytime. Also this wouldn't work if using pure render functions