# Sinon access the original function body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme, sinon-chai

I'm testing React components with sinon chai and enzyme.
I'm writing a plugin having a HOC that will produce a new React component.

I'm not sure what the user will pass to the HOC so I want to check if it is a React Component or not. The only (ugly) way I could find was to adapt from this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658173/1191416)

```
export function isClassComponent(component) {
  return (
    typeof component === 'function' && !!component.prototype.isReactComponent
  )
}

export function isFunctionComponent(component) {
  return (
    typeof component === 'function' && String(component).includes('.createElement')
  );
}

export function isReactComponent(component) {
  return !!(isClassComponent(component) || isFunctionComponent(component))
}
```

This is a vague way to test if the component is a React component or not.

The problem is when my component is a sinon spy.

```
const FnChild = (props) => (<div id="child-fn">{props.children}</div>);
const ChildSpy = spy(FnChild);
```

Now testing `isReactComponent(ChildSpy)` will fail because `isFunctionComponent` will actually inspect the body of the function and in the case of the `ChildSpy` won't be the body of the original function anymore.

I know I shouldn't rely on the body function but that's the best way I could find for my purpose.

Anyway, is there a way to access the original body from the spy? In this case how could I pass it to my `isFunctionComponent`?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of spies in Sinon, there doesn't seem to be a way of accessing the original function (or its body).