# Check wether a function or a class is a valid React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a reliable way to test if a function (stateless component) or a class that extends from React.Component (stateful component) is a valid React component?

Or wether the function (stateless component) or the class' render method returns a valid JSX value?

This should be obvious but just for illustrative purposes, my components are declared like this.

A stateless component is declared like this:

```
const MyComp = (props) => (<div>content</div>)
```

A stateful component is declared like this and may be by HOC's such as Redux.connect:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
  // other methods...

  render () {
    return (<div>content</div>)
  }
}
```

I've tried to use React.isValidElement(MyReactComponentClassOrFunction) but returns false because it's expecting an Object as input.

```
function isValidElement(object) {
  return typeof object === 'object' && object !== null && object.$$typeof === REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE;
}
```

I'm invoking the function as below

```
React.isValidElement(MyComp) // returns false
```

[React.isValidElement doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement)

Comment: Have a look at this, specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658173/6219957

Comment: ok, will have a look at both and if duplicate delete the question. Thanks @brandNew