# Unknown Prop Warning when React.cloneElement used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React component I built for a popup. `PopupContent` will receive a DOM element or another React component as a child.

```
class PopupContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {closePopup:this.props.closePopup})}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `closePopup` prop sets a flag to show/hide the popup

```
closePopup(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        popupInView: false
    })  
}
```

The reason to pass `closePopup` to child is to close the popup from the child component.

This setup works well if the child is a custom React component:

```
<PopupContent>
    <ContentOfThePopup />
</PopupContent>
```

But I get the [Unknown Prop Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html) if the child is a DOM element.

> Warning: React does not recognize the `closePopup` prop on a DOM
>   element.

```
<PopupContent>
    <div>Content Of The Popup </div>
</PopupContent>
```

I could use techniques explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199959/how-to-detect-a-react-component-vs-a-react-element) to distinguish between a DOM element and a React component. But I wanted to check with the community if there is a better way

Comment: Does this work `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, ...this.props)}`?

Comment: Why are you trying to `preventDefault`? You can only receive an event if you use an event name recognized by the dom.

Comment: @Bhojendra Rauniyar It works but then `closePopup` won't get passed down as a prop to the child element.

Comment: @Daniel Lizik Suppose I have a `<a href="#">Close</>` inside the `PopupContent` to close it. Your point is taken, it is not necessary (or can cause problems). But the issue I'm having is not related to this

Comment: closePopup function needs to be passed on to the child so as to execute it which requires your Child element to be a React component. In such a case you need to ensure that the child is a React component

Comment: @Shubham Khatri exactly! But the child can be either a React component or a HTML DOM element (which outputs the warning)

Comment: @ibex, how do you want to handle the case in which the child is an HTML DOM

Comment: Then I don't want to pass the `closePopup`. As mentioned, I could follow what's suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199959/how-to-detect-a-react-component-vs-a-react-element and detect the type of the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up checking the type of the child and conditionally removing the prop `closePopup`

Following condition will be `true` if the child is a HTML DOM element.

`typeof this.props.children.type === 'string`

Answer (score 2):

what does `this.props.children` contain? 
Shouldn't you be iterating over it?

```js
render() {

  return React
    .Children

    // this is the jsx version of cloneElenemnt,
    // better to use in a render function
    .map(Child => <Child.type ...Child.props ...this.props>)
}
```

- [Clone Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)
- [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap)

Comment: `this.props.children` can contain either one HTML DOM element or one React component so no need to iterate. When the child is a HTML DOM element, `closePopup` is an invalid attribute thus I get the Unknown Prop Warning. But when the child is a React component, `closePopup` is a valid a prop that I can pass down.

Comment: And when it is a HTML DOM ELEMENT, you get that warning since closePopup isn’t a valid html attribute

Comment: Correct. I can look at the type of the child and conditionally remove the `closePopup` prop.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not have spurious props floating around.

You should ensure that you are not accidentally forwarding props that were intended to be interpreted by the parent component.

Also you can try `{...this.props}` format to pass your data instead of using `cloneElement(element, this.props)`

Comment: This was a direct citation from https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html which I mentioned in the question. I do know the cause of this is `closePopup` is an invalid HTML attribute. And I don't have a problem with passing down the props to child. The problem is the child can be either HTML element or a React component. the attribute `closePopup` is a invalid in former but valid in latter