# Reliable way to tell if a function is a functional React component or just a plain function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given a functional React component:

```
const AComponent = (props) {
    // ...
    return <div>{...}</div>;
};
```

And a plain JS function which may or may not return a React element, e.g.:

```js
function aFunction() {
    // Returns React element.
    return <div></div>
}

// OR:

function aFunction() {
    // Doesn't return a React element, doesn't have to do with React at all.
    return 123;
}
```

How do I implement the following function:

```js
function isTrulyFunctionalComponent(fn) {
    // ???
}

console.log(isTrulyFunctionalComponent(AComponent)); // true
console.log(isTrulyFunctionalComponent(aFunction)); // false
```

so that it works even when the code is transpiled and minified?

I thought about checking `fn.name` within `isTrulyFunctionalComponent`, e.g.:

```js
function isTrulyFunctionalComponent(fn) {
    // Won't work when minifying
    return typeof fn === "function" && fn.name[0] === fn.name[0].toUpperCase();
}
```

but when I minify the code, `fn.name` is empty and the code above breaks...

Thanks for the attention!

**EDIT**: I am trying to achieve the following:

```
function MyComponent({
    componentForDataItem = AComponent,
    data = []
} = {}) {
    const componentIsReactComponent = isTrulyFunctionalComponent(componentForDataItem);

    return data.map(dataItem => {
        // componentForDataItem can either be a functional component
        // or a function returning a React component to use for the given dataItem. 
        const Component = componentIsReactComponent
            ? componentForDataItem
            : componentForDataItem(dataItem);
        return (
            <Component {...} />
    });

}

<MyComponent data={[...]} /> // Uses the default AComponent for all items of data

<MyComponent data={[...]} componentForDataItem={dataItem => {
   // Custom logic for a specific dataItem, e.g.:
   return if dataItem.value === "check" ? AnotherComponent : AComponent;
}} />
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: React functional components **are** regular, plain functions.

Comment: Please, check my edit.

Comment: @DrewReese I know it, but still I need to differentiate between a regular, plain function which is managed by React (receives props, may have hooks or not, etc.) and a plain function which in my case acts as a factory for a specific `dataItem`. Please, check my edit.

Comment: You can't tell unless you execute the function. `function GoGuess() { return Math.random() > 0.5 ? <div/> : "Hello" }`

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199959/how-to-detect-a-react-component-vs-a-react-element

Comment: I would basically need to know if the given function accepts props and that that is managed by React, that could work... But how?

Comment: @YashJoshi Already did before writing this question, didn't find a solution. The provided implementation for `function isFunctionComponent` there is fragile, because it relies on `String(component).includes('return React.createElement')`, which won't work when transpiling and minifying the sources. Also, the plain JS function `aFunction` in my case may as well be a function returning a React element, as I have mentioned, so this check won't work.

Comment: The root cause of your problem seems to be that you mix React components and other data types. Consider not doing that.