# How to support different types of icons being passed to a react component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a couple of components and I need to show icons in my componnets.

Let's say my component's usage code would look like this:

```
<SomeComponent
    ...otherProps
    icon=X
/>
```

I realized that developers tend to use icons in a couple of ways:

1. `icon='done'`
2. `icon={Done}`
3. `icon={<Done />}`
4. `icon={doneSvg}`

To be more versatile I created this `CustomIcon` component:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

const CustomIcon = ({ icon }) => {
    console.log(icon);
    switch (typeof icon) {
        case 'object':
            if (icon.props) {
                return icon;
            }
            return <>{icon}</>;
        case 'function':
            return icon()
        case 'string':
            if (icon.indexOf('svg') > -1) {
                return icon;
            }
            return <Icon>{icon}</Icon>;
        default:
            return <span>Iconless</span>;
    }
}

export default CustomIcon;
```

But it fails when I pass it `icon={DoneIcon}` with the following message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-moore-poru3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What is DoneIcon?

Comment: @iunfixit, in this case, `DoneIcon` is `import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accounting for a memoized component function(which has `{$$typeof, type, compare}`)

```
const CustomIcon = ({ icon }) => {
    console.log(icon);
    
    switch (typeof icon) {
        case 'object':
            const iconType = typeof icon?.type;
            if (
             iconType === 'function'
               || (iconType === 'object' && typeof icon.type?.render === 
               'function'))    {
              const Icon = icon
              return <Icon/>;
            }
            if (icon.props) {
                return icon;
            }
            return <>{icon}</>;
        case 'function':
            return icon()
        case 'string':
            if (icon.indexOf('svg') > -1) {
                return icon;
            }
            return <Icon>{icon}</Icon>;
        default:
            return <span>Iconless</span>;
    }
}
```

Also for arrays that you could check with length

You could also use a destructuring alias like the other answer

### Explanation

When you memoize a component you get an object, like the following

```
{type: Object, compare: null}
```

For a function component `type` is a function instead. You can confirm it with the following

```
const MyIcon = React.memo(() => {
  return <DeleteOutlinedIcon/>
})

console.log(MyIcon)
```

The code above checks for this situation, and let JSX handle it

Comment: I tried it. Did not solve the issue. I'm trying to create a code sandbox for it.

Comment: I believe that was a class component, updated answer

Comment: Your new code did it. Thank you so much. Can you also explain the theory behind it? I mean, it's so confusing without theory.

Comment: I also provided a code sandbox. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Updated let me know if it explains well

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render a plain JavaScript object to the DOM. This error occurs due to the type detection switch provided as React components also match `typeof Object`

You can visit this answer to gain insight into proper React component detection: [How to detect a React component vs. a React element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199959/how-to-detect-a-react-component-vs-a-react-element)

In retrospect, I'd rewrite this component to something like this:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

function isClassComponent(component) {
    return (
        typeof component === 'function' && 
        !!component.prototype.isReactComponent
    )
}

function isFunctionComponent(component) {
    return (
        typeof component === 'function' && 
        String(component).includes('return React.createElement')
    )
}

function isReactComponent(component) {
    return (
        isClassComponent(component) || 
        isFunctionComponent(component)
    )
}

const CustomIcon = ({ icon: ProvidedIcon }) => {
    // Order
    // 1. Handle React components first
    if (isReactComponent(ProvidedIcon)) {
        return <ProvidedIcon />
    }
    // Provide code to handle svg/string paths & a default case.
}

export default CustomIcon;
```